# MATLAB: set keyboard shortcut to go to line where current code execution stopped

Tags: matlab, keyboard, editor, shortcut

I would like to set a key short-cut. e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or so, to go in the editor into the file and line where the 'keyboard' command stopped the current code execution in order to debug faster. Is this possible? Or does it exist already? Now, even when I click the function in the debugger tab, it doesn't go there if that function was last clicked and in the mean time you moved manually to another function in the editor. I first have to click another function in the pop down menu and than re-click to function I want to go to. Very annoying.

Comment: I found some other older posts on this topic, under "go the current cursor" and in those posts it didn't get solved and this functionality didn't seem to exist in MATLAB yet at the time of those posts... .

Comment: you can run `dbstop if error` and I believe it will do the job

Comment: I debug by placing 'keyboard' in relevant portions of my script. So there is no error occurring before that (usually :p). E.g. I place this in the code
"
if subset_i == 2
   keyboard
end
"

Comment: Oh, I understood that you where breaking the execution with the keyboard (i.e. CTRL+C).

Comment: @Luis Mendo This seems interesting, I'm gonna try that if nothing better pops up. I say this, because during debugging and switching view between different  functions/scripts files in the editor to adjust various parts of the code, I wanna go back to the current code execution stop repeatedly, rerunning some particular line there e.g. until it works correctly. Your solution would only make it easy (automatic even) to go there once. But thanks, seems a cool fix.

Comment: Luis, where did your answer go? It was good!